# What is a cheap way to get from NYC to Boston, MA?

Tags: budget, transportation, new-york-city, boston

The first option that ran through my mind was taking a Greyhound bus, and it costs $40. Any other options that you guys know of? The duration of the travel is not of essence. I'm ok if it takes longer.

Comment: Considered hitchhiking? It's free and not as dangerous as people claim ;)

Comment: Never tried it, but may consider it.

Comment: http://www.ridebuzz.org/craigslist_rideshare_city_state_usa_canada

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Aside Greyhound (costing 30-60`USD`), [Rome2rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/New-York/Boston) shows various other bus options including [Yo Bus](http://yobus.com/) costing 20`USD`. There is also a bus combination using [BoltBus](https://www.boltbus.com/) which supposedly costs 19-24`USD`. [MegaBus](http://www.megabus.com/) can get you there for as low as 11`USD` one way depending on what day of the week you're traveling and how far in the future you book your ticket. The bus trip takes 4 to 4.5 hours

Comment: damn you beat me by seconds ;)

Comment: @MarkMayo Gotta stay in the game ... uhm ... I mean gotta keep up that 99% answered statistic. :)

Comment: It's 4.5 hours if traffic in NYC cooperates, which it often does not. If you intend to connect in NYC to travel elsewhere, keep in mind that you may arrive late. I also find it highly amusing that Yo! Bus is jointly owned by Greyhound and Peter Pan.

Comment: I'm not connecting. I'm going from NYC.

Comment: I've bookmarked rome2rio.com. Will come in handy.

Comment: I've never rode either; but my sister says Megabus is much nicer than Greyhound and (at least on the NYC to Pittsburgh route) faster because it makes a lot fewer stops on the way.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is http://us.megabus.com/. It is cheaper and faster compared to greyhound. And it's less than ***$20.00*** . It's way better than greyhound in my opinion.

Comment: +1 Can you expand on why it's faster? I'm not doubting you, I would just like to see some numbers.

Comment: In my experience with another Megabus line in the region, Megabus arrives consistently early by about 15-30 minutes and leaves on time. The buses themselves are also much nicer than Greyhound - smoother, quieter, nicer seats, etc.

Comment: @br1ckb0t said it's exactly my experience too.And greyhound buses doesn't come on time some times.Waited 2 hours more last week when I travelled to KC through greyhound

Comment: Plus free wifi on most megabuses

Answer (score 1):

According to [Busbud](https://www.busbud.com/en/bus-schedules-results/Boston,Massachusetts,UnitedStates/NewYork,NewYork,UnitedStates?departure-date=2015-03-13&adults=1&children=0&seniors=0&child_ages=&senior_ages=&discount_code=) a bus between Boston and New York City will run anywhere between 27 and 34$. A train ride from Boston to NYC will run anywhere between 74 and 255$.

Might be worth checking out "Carpool World", I've never personally used it but this seems like something you'd be interested in: https://www.carpoolworld.com/carpool_ride.html.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.fungwahbus.com/default.html is rumored to restart service again soon. They go Chinatown to Chinatown. They were  shut down in 2013 as an "imminent hazard to public safety" because of various safety violations.

At the time it was $10 per one way and it's a free adventure ride as well :-)